# [Edited]setOnFocusChangeListener doesn't work on Gallery in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, gallery

When I make a `setOnFocusChangeListener` for a `imageView` in a `getView` method in the adapter of the gallery which is in a `listView` the listener doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Because an imageview can't take a setOnItemClickListener. It can take a setOnClickListener. Could you please paste your code for your getView and setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: imageView.setOnFocusChangeListener( new OnFocusChangeListener()
     {

   @Override
   public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int s = 0;
    if (arg1 == false)
    {
     arg0.destroyDrawingCache();
     arg0 = null;
     d.recycle();
    }
   }
      
     });

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you don't already have an android:onClick event in your layout file. Which is inflated for The ListView rows.

Comment: please Consider adding these as comment.

Comment: It was my mistake. I'm sorry.

Comment: Oh I mean setOnFocusChangeListener not onItemListener

Answer (score 0):

Because an imageview can't take a setOnItemClickListener. It can take a setOnClickListener.

use setOnClickListener instead